# How to pass variable length arguments as arguments on another function in Golang?

Tags: function, go, variadic-functions

How to pass variable length arguments in `Go`? for example, I want to call

```
func MyPrint(format string, args ...interface{}) {
  fmt.Printf("[MY PREFIX] " + format, ???)
}

// to be called as: MyPrint("yay %d", 213) 
//              or  MyPrint("yay")
//              or  MyPrint("yay %d %d",123,234)
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Ah found it...functions that accept variable length arguments are called **Variadic Functions**. Example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func MyPrint(format string, args ...interface{}) {
  fmt.Printf("[MY PREFIX] " + format, args...)
}

func main() {
 MyPrint("yay %d %d\n",123,234);
 MyPrint("yay %d\n ",123);
 MyPrint("yay %d\n");
}
```

Comment: For those who want the reference...see [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#printing)

Comment: Note that the final call to MyPrint is missing a parameter and so fmt will complain that the argument to be printed by the %d is missing